# How to precisely control where script tag is inserted using Next Script

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

I'm currently trying to add a third party script to my Next.js application. The script inserts an iframe directly below the script tag. So I need precise control over where the script tag is located on the page.

I'm currently using [next/script](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/script) because regular script tags are preventing the iframe from rendering. However, the [next/script](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/script) tag seems to relocate the script based on the strategy used: Using beforeInteractive strategy inserts the script into the head. afterInteractive and lazyOnload insert it somewhere near the bottom of the page.

If I have something like the following:

```
<div id="script-container">
  <Script id="script" async /* other attributes */ />
</div>
```

How would I ensure that the script remains inside the script-container div when the page loads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the somewhat hacky solution I came up with.

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react'
import Script from 'next/script'

export const ScriptComponent = (props) => {
  const containerRef = useRef(null)

  function moveScript() {
    containerRef.current.appendChild(this)
  }

  return (
    <div ref={containerRef} id="script-container">
      <Script
        id="script"
        type="text/javascript"
        src="#url"
        async
        onLoad={moveScript}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Basically add an onLoad function that moves the script back to the container. I'm unsure how consistent this solution is overall since it depends on the script being moved before the iframe gets loaded, but it appears to be working with the script I'm using.

Comment: Good question and answer @rrne332, thanks for this. By the way, I got ```TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.```
And then noticed `this` is actually `undefined` when `moveScript` is being executed.

Comment: @MaestroDever It's hard to tell what the issue is without seeing the code you're using. One thing I would say is to make sure your moveScript function is declared as a regular function and not an arrow function. If that's not the problem, you can try to fetch the script Node using another method like `document.getElementById`.